# Page displays completely blank

Tags: solspace-freeform, multi-site-manager

I am using Freeform Pro on a second site with Multiple Site Manager. As soon as I include the Freeform code:

```
    {exp:freeform:form 
    form_name="careers" 
    required="first_name|last_name|email|message"
    return="careers/thank-you"
    user_email_field="email"
}
    <table class="col2">
      <tr>
        <td>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="{freeform:label:first_name} *" >
                <span class="clear"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="{freeform:label:last_name} *" >
                <span class="clear"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="{freeform:label:email} *" >
                <span class="clear"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="{freeform:label:phone}" >
                <span class="clear"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="{freeform:label:message} *" ></textarea>
                <span class="clear"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
                <h5>{freeform:label:upload_resume}</h5>
                <h6>(Word, Pages or PDF formats Only)</h6><br>{freeform:field:upload_resume show="2"}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="captcha">
                <p>{freeform:captcha}</p><p><input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="TYPE THE CHARACTERS ABOVE" ></input></p>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="buttons"><span><input class="button1" type="reset" value="Clear" /></span><span><input class="button2" type="submit" value="Send" /></span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p class="required">* Required Field</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

on a form template, the entire page displays completely blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your complete Freeform code? Two things to try. Make sure any conditionals on the page are correct, like not closing an if statement. Also, remove code between the {exp:freeform:form}{/exp:freeform:form} tags and simply the page to try and isolate where the problem is.

Comment: @AlexRoper I just added the full form code. I tried to remove everything inbetween the {exp:freeform:form} tag pair and it still causes the entire page to appear blank. It seems it only does this when I try to link to the Freeform module in any way.

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: I just turned it on. Error message states:"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Addon_builder_freeform in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-63-24-24.ip.secureserver.net/www.aultec.com/public/system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform-old/addon_builder/addon_builder.php on line 32"

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I just noticed after I posted this error message that it was referncing my old backup folder for Freeform (not sure why). After I deleted it, the page loaded as normal.